# How to Update score in Firebase Unity instead of replacing/re-writing it?

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database

Whenever I reopen the game and start scoring again it replaces the previous data. Please help me with this and tell me where I'm doin it wrong.

I'm using Firebase Realtime Database.

This is my score script down below:

```
public static int cashValue;

Text cash;

void Start()    
{    
  cash = GetComponent();    
}

void Update()    
{    
  cash.text = "" + cashValue;    
}
```

This is where I save the score in Firebase Realtime Database:

```
private IEnumerator UpdateKills(int _kills)    
{    
  //Set the currently logged in user kills    
  var DBTask = DBreference.Child("users").Child(User.UserId).Child("kills").SetValueAsync(_kills);

  yield return new WaitUntil(predicate: () => DBTask.IsCompleted);

  if (DBTask.Exception != null)    
  {    
    Debug.LogWarning(message: $"Failed to register task with {DBTask.Exception}");    
  }    
  else    
  {    
    //Kills are now updated    
  }    
}
```

And This is Where I Retrieve the data from Firebase Realtime Database:

```
private IEnumerator LoadUserData()    
{    
  //Get the currently logged in user data    
  var DBTask = DBreference.Child("users").Child(User.UserId).GetValueAsync();

  yield return new WaitUntil(predicate: () => DBTask.IsCompleted);

  if (DBTask.Exception != null)    
  {    
    Debug.LogWarning(message: $"Failed to register task with {DBTask.Exception}");    
  }    
  else if (DBTask.Result.Value == null)    
  {    
    //No data exists yet    
    xpField.text = "0";    
    killsField.text = "0";    
    deathsField.text = "0";    
  }     
  else    
  {    
    //Data has been retrieved    
    DataSnapshot snapshot = DBTask.Result;    
    xpField.text = snapshot.Child("xp").Value.ToString();    
    killsField.text = snapshot.Child("kills").Value.ToString();    
    deathsField.text = snapshot.Child("deaths").Value.ToString();    
  }    
}
```

It works perfectly, but the only problem is that it replacing the Score instead of updating it or start from where I left.

Comment: Before the first kill update, you must load the data in your local game from the database.

Comment: can you please explain a bit more? Do you mean I should use playerprefs? or something else..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something to watch out for is that you might be falling victim to caching. Basically, `GetValueAsync` typically returns whatever's cached locally (unless you disable persistence -- which you probably shouldn't) and asks the server for an update. `SetValueAsync` writes to the local cache and eventually syncs it up in the background.

Therefore, to update a value, you should always use a Transaction. From https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/unity/save-data#save_data_as_transactions

```
private void UpdateKills(int _kills)  {
  DBreference.Child("users").Child(User.UserId).Child("kills").RunTransaction(mutableData => {
    // if the data isn't an int or is null, just make it 0
    // then add the new number of kills
    var kills = ((mutableData.value as? int) ?? 0) + _kills;
    return TransactionResult.Success(mutableData);
  });
}
```

This would require reworking your logic so that rather than saving the total kills, you record the delta. Then this transaction would run repeatedly until it succeeds (usually once, unless your data is out of sync in which case usually twice).

For getting data, you're best off registering [`ValueChanged`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/unity/retrieve-data#value-events) listeners and updating your UI directly from those. This way you're always in sync with your server, and it's smart enough to use a local cache so you don't have to worry about always blocking on a network access (you'll get a null if there's nothing cached). Also, as the local cache updates in the Transaction, you will get ValueChanged events with the latest data.

Obviously, not every game can be stable around randomly receiving value updates from a server. But if you can move your data to be more reactive around Realtime Database, you'll make the best use of its inbuilt local caching and sync logic.

Answer (score 1):

The flow should go like this:

```
int myData;
bool isMyDataLoaded = false;

void Start() {
   LoadMyData();
}

void LoadMyData() {
    StartCoroutine(IELoadMyData());
}

void SetMyData() {
    if(isMyDataLoaded) {
        // Set only if the data from database was retreived
        StartCoroutine(IESetMyData());
    }
}

IEnumerator IELoadMyData() {
    // Load your data from database here
    if(<fetch was successful>) {
        myData = <the result>;
        isMyDataLoaded = true; // Set data loaded as true
    }
}

IEnumerator IESetMyData() {
    // Update your data here
}
```

Now whenever you want to update, Call SetMyData. It will only set the new data in the DB if the data was first fetched in the local game successfully.